# How to express recursive calls in higher dimensions

Tags: javascript, math, computer-science, paradigms

Just a question of curiosity, not serious.

In the JS language I know that a factorial operation can be defined in the following form.

```
function factorial(n) {
    if (n === 1) return 1;
    return factorial(n - 1) * n;
}
```

Then I defined a **factorial of a factorial** operation in the following form, and called it `super_factorial_1`. There is a similar [description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Superfactorial) on Wikipedia.

```
function super_factorial_1(n) {
    if (n === 1) return factorial(1);
    return super_factorial_1(n - 1) * factorial(n);
}
```

Similarly, using the `super_factorial_1` as an operator, the `super_factorial_2` is defined here:

```
function super_factorial_2(n) {
    if (n === 1) return super_factorial_1(1);
    return super_factorial_2(n - 1) * super_factorial_1(n);
}
```

Now the question is how to define the `super_factorial_n` operation, and the `super_factorial_n_n`, and furthermore, the `super_factorial_n..._n{n of n}`.

I have used a crude method to define the above `super_factorial_n` operation, but I don't think this method is good enough.

```
function super_factorial_n(n, m) {
    const fns = Array(n + 1).fill(0);
    fns[0] = factorial;
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        fns[i] = function (m) {
            if (m === 1) return fns[i - 1](1);
            return fns[i](m - 1) * fns[i - 1](m);
        }
    }
    return fns[n](m);
}
```

Perhaps this is an optimisation direction for the process programming paradigm. :)

Comment: all the theory around this stuff exists in fractal realities  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal

Comment: "but I don't think this method is good enough." And the reason you  do not think it is good enough?

Comment: @epascarello This approach generates a large number of functions at runtime, but the purpose of generating these functions is not to implement a function factory, but simply to use them to derive values. So I thought there should be a way to simplify this process.
This is similar to the dilemma we face when adding multi-threading support to a single-threaded language.

Comment: You don't need to generate the sub-functions. They are already parameterized. Something like `function super_factorial(n, m) { if (n==0) return 1; if (m==1) return super_factorial(n-1, 1); else return super_factorial(n, m-1); * super_factorial(n-1, m) }`. (That's not quite right, but that's the idea. It was confusing following your discussion because `n` changed meaning partway through.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pseudo code

```js
// j is the level number
// i = j - 1
function super_factorial_j(n) {
    if (n === 1)
        return super_factorial_i(1);
    return super_factorial_j(n - 1) * super_factorial_i(n);
}
```

Parameterize the `j` and `i`

```js
function super_factorial(j, n) {
    if (n === 1)
        return super_factorial(j - 1, 1);
    return super_factorial(j, n - 1) * super_factorial(j - 1, n);
}
```

Add the exit condition

```js
function super_factorial(j, n) {
    if (j == 0) { // or j == 1 for one based level number
        if (n === 1)
            return 1;
        return super_factorial(0, n - 1) * n;
    }
    if (n === 1)
        return super_factorial(j - 1, 1);
    return super_factorial(j, n - 1) * super_factorial(j - 1, n);
}
```

Of course this is just one of the many ways to go. And it is hard to say if this is better then any other one. Recursive functions are generally stack memory consuming. But the value are likely grow very fast, it is not very practice to call it with big numbers anyway.